Host can't be null
I'm currently working in a migration where I have the code already implemented, but any time that I try to run the migration I got this issue:

An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Host can't be null`

I already try this:
Add-Migration MigrationName -Connection "host=localhost;port=1234;database=mydatabase;user id=admin;password=password;"

but then I got this error:

Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Connection'`

I also tried the dotnet ef commands but same, when I specify the --connection I got this:

Unrecognized option --connection`

Have someone ever had this issue before?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#add-migration

I believe you need to change 'host' to 'server'

That did  not worked, thanks

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The project dependencies were updated and one of those was EF core and the new version required to add a new environment variable to my machine. This specifically:
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: LocalDevelopment
Hope this helps someone.
